# how to determine $x^2 \equiv a \pmod m$ solvable if m,a not coprime

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I am reading books about Number theory now. It's hard to me.
Seems I use quadratic residues to determine if $x^2 \equiv a\pmod m$, but
I don't know how when m, a not coprime. More specifically, like:

$x^2 \equiv 2\pmod 8$ // is this solvable? I know $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ solvable

$x^2 \equiv 6 \pmod 8$ // is this solvable?

Comment: I think it's fair to say that $x^2\equiv2\pmod{8}$ is insoluble

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you clarify more?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I means $x^2 = 1 \pmod 4 $ is solvable.

Comment: you can prove squares are only 0,1,and 4 mod 8 if you really wanted to.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is there a proof around there?

Comment: Also don't make a big deal of quadratic reciprocity. $(\frac{5}{p}) = (\frac{p}{5})$ a simple case [follows from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_using_Quadratic_Gauss_Sums) $\sum_{n=1}^5 \zeta_5^{n^2} = \sqrt{5}$, and the general case follows the same lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime such that $p^2\mid a$ and $p^2\mid m$, the you must have $p\mid  x$ so $p^2\mid x^2$ so $p^2\mid x^2-a$ only if $p^2\mid a $. In this case, you reduce to the question:

$$y^2\equiv \frac{a}{p^2}\pmod{\frac{m}{p^2}}$$

This solves the cases in your question, since $2^2\mid 8$, but $2^2\not\mid 2$ and $2^2\not\mid 6$, so there cannot be solutions.

If $p\mid a$ and $p\mid m$ but $p^2\not\mid m$, then  $p$ is relatively prime to $\frac{m}{p}$, and by Chinese Remainder Theorem, this has a solution if and only if we can solve both:

$$\begin{align}x_1^2&\equiv 0\pmod{p}\\
x_2^2&\equiv a\pmod{\frac mp}
\end{align}$$
But the first has a solution, so $x^2\equiv a\pmod{m}$ has a solution in this case if and only if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{\frac mp}$ has a solution.

Repeated use of these two reductions lets you reduce the question to a question with $(a,m)=1$ or conclude the equation has no solution (if some step has a $p^2\mid m$ and $p^2\not\mid a$.)